# JavaFx2 IllegalStateException with Label.setText

Tags: java, thread-safety, javafx-2

Why when i use a simple Thread like this :

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run(){
while(true){
  .....
 idLabel.setText(Date.toString);
 Thread.sleep(1000);`
}
t.start();
```

i got this Error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

but if i use an input text (like idInputText) and not a label i didn't have the error ??

Answer (score 6):

All UI operation for JavaFX should be performed on FX application thread. You are creating a new `Thread t` which is not a FX application thread. Hence the exception message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Not on FX application thread;** currentThread = Thread-4

You need to use [Platform#runLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) method for such operations, like as following:

```
while(true){
    .....
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            idLabel.setText(Date.toString);
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);`
}
```

Comment: But i've the error message only if i use a Label, and if i use Platform.runlater doesn't works !

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the whole code? To check it out. Maybe there is another error in another point of the code.